# append or create a new xml file from php

Tags: php, xml

I have a php file which is created to append data to a xml but if the file is not there it is supposed to create the file.But when I run the php it gives me output that I didn't expect which is added in the end of the question. XML file is not getting created. The following is the php file.

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/xml');

function createXML($doc) {
    $markers = $doc->createElement('markers');
    $markers  = $doc->appendChild($markers);
}
$url = '../../data/data.xml';
$lat  = "bla1";
$lng  = "bla2";
$address  = "bla3";
$doc = new DomDocument();
if (!file_exists($url)){
    createXML($doc);
}
else {
    $doc->preserveWhiteSpace = FALSE; 
    $doc->load($url);  
}
$markers = $doc->getElementsByTagName('markers')->item(0);
$marker = $doc->createElement('marker');
$marker = $markers->appendChild($marker);   
$marker->setAttribute("lat", $lat);
$marker->setAttribute("lng", $lng);
$marker->setAttribute("address", $address);
$doc->formatOutput = true;
$doc->save($url);

?>
```

when I run the php file I get the following output

> **Fatal error** :  Call to a member function appendChild() on a non-object in 
>   **/home[...]/saveMarkers.php** on line **30**

can you tell me what I have done wrong in here thank you in advance

Comment: I solved it by `echo`ing the code...

Comment: see solution here: https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3#echoxml

Comment: @PavelJanicek sorry, I removed google-api tag you've added, I thought that was the OP and I did not (and still do not) see the link with google-api

Comment: Pavel the link u sent is adding to an xml file and it uses a database. what I want is to add values to a file which is already there.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I just tested your code is fine and doing what is expected, You don't need to use header if you don't want to echo 
anyway verify you have permissions to write in the destination directory

Comment: you are welcome but somebody has a problem with your code getting work so that he marked my answer as "not useful" !

Comment: I just noticed that too. but it's working for me. because of you I got lots of work done. i tried to vote up but it didn't work